# como controlar la ejecucion de javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy programando en javascript (soy nuevo) y me he percatado de que a veces no se ejecuta de forma secuencial, he visto que es porque se ejecuta de forma asincrona.

Hasta ahora he medio escapado con la funcion setTimeout, pero me gustaria saber si hay otras formas de controlar la ejecucion de javascript para que haga exactamente lo que quiero.

En mi caso particular, tengo este codigo donde accedo a firebase para obtener el numero de hijos de un nodo:

```
      firebase.initializeApp(config);

      var database = firebase.database();


             var numerojaja;
             //     TO-DO : obtener el numero de peliculas  
           firebase.database().ref('/peliculas/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {  

               numerojaja=snapshot.numChildren();
               console.log(numerojaja);
           });

             console.log(numerojaja);

             //                 **********
             var numero_p=3;        // de momento 
             var nombre_p="hhola";
             var descripcion="esto es una descripcion";
             var reputacion="y esto una reputacion";
             var cartelera="esto es una direccion de una imagen";


             // for(etc.......){
             document.write('<tr>');
             document.write('<th scope="row">'+nombre_p+'</th>');
             document.write('<td>'+descripcion+' </td>');
             document.write('<td>'+reputacion+'</td>');
             document.write('<td><img src="'+direccion+'" class=".img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre " style="max-width: 20%;"> </td>');
             document.write('</tr>');

             // end for.......
```

El problema esta dentro de la siguiente seccion de codigo:

```
             var numerojaja;
             //     TO-DO : obtener el numero de peliculas  
           firebase.database().ref('/peliculas/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {  

               numerojaja=snapshot.numChildren();
               console.log(numerojaja);
           });
```

Javascript decide en primer lugar saltarse la ejecucion dentro de la funcion y continua, y una vez ha terminado de ejecutar el resto, ejecuta la funcion. Haciendo que cuando quiero acceder a dicho valor no pueda porque todavia no se ha ejecutado.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes algún de ejemplo de tu problema que puedas reproducir? Recuerda que siempre debes incluir en tu pregunta un código que sea por lo menos verificable, mira [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: claro, dame un momento

Comment: Investiga sobre async/await eso te ayudará a controlar la ejecución asíncrona como si fuera síncrona (pero no lo es). Solo funciona en ES6 en adelante

Comment: muchas gracias, he revisado por encima y creo que con eso podre proseguir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vale amigo, el problema es que, ¿**porque quieres manipular los datos de tu snapshot fuera del evento**? A de mas **database** dispone de un método con una función callback (`then()`) para ejecutar tu código de manera inmediata y consecutiva a la obtención de los datos. JavaScript en si es un lenguaje asíncrono, por lo que es el comportamiento esperado, [mira esto](https://lemoncode.net/lemoncode-blog/2018/1/29/javascript-asincrono).

Naturalmente si quieres hacer algo en una función, tienes que terminar de hacerlo dentro de la función, a menos que hagas que esta retorne un valor especifico y llamarla al momento de ejecutar el código.

**Mira los siguientes ejemplos:**

```js
var str;

setTimeout(function(){
  str = "hola"
},2000);

console.log(str);
```

JavaScript nunca va a esperar a que pasen dos segundos para que puedas imprimir la variable estando fuera de la función, para eso es la función en si para cambiar el valor y a de mas si no fuese así seria imposible cargar una pagina web... entonces ¿por que es necesario imprimirla afuera si puedo hacerlo adentro? es la pregunta correcta.

Recordemos que **una función no es lo mismo que una condicional**... veamos el siguiente código:

```js
var str;

if (str == undefined){
  str = "hola"
}

console.log(str);
```

Esto funciona porque la condicional evalúa secuencialmente los datos que se estan comparando y cambia o ejecuta dependiendo de ello, por lo que esta vez no va a ser `undefined`.

Ahora, si tienes una función que invocas al momento de la ejecución en tiempo real del codigo, esta vez si va a retornar el resultado deseado:

```js
var str;

    function hola(str){
      str = "hola"
      return str
    }

    console.log(hola(str));
```

**Entonces, la conclusión:**

Si necesitas ejecutar código que tiene que ver con la función dentro de la función en si, hazlo dentro y el resultado sera sincronizado.

**Como debería ser:**

```js
var str;

    setTimeout(function(){
      str = "hola"
      console.log(str);
    },2000);
```

Como valor adicional te **recomiendo que leas** las documentaciones de las herramientas que utilizas, por ejemplo:

> **Cuando recibes tu snapshot en tu codigo pones**:
>   `"numerojaja=snapshot.numChildren();"`

Esto va a ser igual a `undefined` porque la snapshot es un objeto del que que necesitas recoger su valor utilizando el método `val()` de **database** (o JQuery), la forma correcta seria:

```
var data = snapshot.val();
var numerojaja = data.numChildren; //Sin () a de mas ya que no es una funcion, es un objeto.
```

Entonces la forma correcta seria, ejecutando tu código dentro de la función del evento o dentro de la función de `then()`:

```js
db.ref('/peliculas').once('value', function(snapshot) {  
   var data =snapshot.val();
   var numerojaja = data.numChildren;
   console.log(numerojaja);
 }).then(function(){
   console.log(numerojaja)           
 });
```

Aquí te dejo [Lee y escribe datos en la Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?hl=es-419) y [Detecta eventos de valores](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data?hl=es-419#listen_for_value_events).

Espero que te sea de ayuda, ¡Un saludo!.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, muchas gracias, perdona si cometo muchas tonterias, el tema es que me mandaron un proyector en la universidad, basicamente sin acalararnos nada de javascript o firebase :( . Mil gracias por la ayuda y la paciencia

Comment: No te preocupes para eso estamos! Saludos.